# How exactly should I escape the awk $ variables in a shell script function?

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am trying to use awk inside a shell script function, but can't seem to find a reference that tells me how to properly escape the awk variable ($4). Inside the function it keeps getting replaced at the 4th item passed to the function (Null).

```
iHealthGetFile()
{
    fileID=$(cat qkViews/${dir}iHealth-Files.json|grep -B5 '${1}'|grep id|awk '{print $4}'|sed 's/,//g; s/\"//g')
    echo $fileID
    echo "Retrieving file $1 as $fileID from ID: $ID"
}
```

(disclaimer: Yes, I could probably do something differently with the piped commands... but my main goal is to figure out the escaping of the $4 first.)

Comment: `awk '{print $4}'` is the correct way to return the fourth field.  You have put `$4` in single-quotes which is the correct way to protect it from the shell.  The error is caused by something else.  Provide details and maybe we can help.

Comment: @john1024, changing $4 in the awk script portion to '$4' still doesn't prevent the $4 from being evaluated as a parameter to the function, unfortunately.

Comment: The way that you have it in the question, `awk '{print $4}'`, is correct if you are expecting awk to evaluate `$4` as the fourth field on the input line.  The single quotes prevent the shell from altering the command before awk is run.

Comment: Did @roaima's answer work for?  If not, you need to make more clear what your input looks like and what output you expect.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell without any contextual data, the error is not in your `awk` code, but within your first `grep`, which is looking for the literal four characters `${1}`. I suspect this was intended to be the first parameter passed to your function.

I've altered your code a little. If you really intended the `echo $fileID` to remove extraneous whitespace you'll want to remove the double quotes I've added around the variable there.

You're also using a couple of global variables. Mixing local variables (`$1`) and global variables (`$dir` and `$ID`) is not particularly good coding practice, but there are times in a script where pragamatism may need to win.

```
iHealthGetFile()
{
    fileID=$(
        grep -B5 "$1" "qkViews/${dir}iHealth-Files.json" |
        awk '/id/ {print $4}'|
        tr -d ',"'
    )
    echo "$fileID"
    echo "Retrieving file $1 as $fileID from ID: $ID"
}
```

Comment: The $1 is correct, it's the filename passed to the function.

The function is called like so, "iHealthGetFile /some/directory/some/FileName"

In this case, like any shell script function, $1 represents the first parameter passed when the function is called. This is desirable. However, the replacement of $4 in the awk command is not since it is not intended to be the fourth parameter passed, but instead part of the awk function.

Comment: @JerryLees great; I've understood what your code is trying to do. The problem was in the first `grep` statement. There is nothing wrong with your `awk` statement as presented in your question

Answer (score 0):

In your question you claim that awk returns null as a result of $4 passed to the shell function is null.

The reason that your awk (or your whole pipe) returns null is not due to a kind of confussion with shell function parameters.
It is just because whatever is feeding awk with data (left part of your awk pipe) has not a valid 4th field .

This test will prove it:

```
$ function tt { echo "1:$1-2:$2-3:$3-4:$4"; echo "first second third fourth" |awk '{print $4}'; }
$ tt one two #call the function with only two parameters. 3 and 4 are null
1:one-2:two-3:-4: #Parameters passed to function
fourth #awk result
```

As you can see , awk result is not affected by function parameters . If the data provided to awk are valid, 4th field of these data will be returned.